# Page tab shows blank content

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page

I'm trying to add a tab to my fan page.
I've done this hundreds of time and everything was ok but this time I get a blank tab.
I added the Page Tab URL and the secure Page Tab URL in the app settings and I can access the pages directly but when I try to access through the tab, it's blank. My ssl cert is OK.

[link to my tab](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gisheft2/161692587243570?sk=app_404902092873645)